# Should ports be available immediately after closing?

Tags: sockets, tcp, port

I've been writing a simple TCP/IP Server in Python between two clients and a server. Currently, when I try to rerun the program immediately after it closes on the same port, the shell is informing me that the port is busy.

I think that this should indicate that somehow not properly closing a connection somewhere but I can't seem to find any lingering sockets.

My question is, is this assumption correct? Am I leaving open a socket or is this behavior otherwise normal? If so, does anyone have any advice as to how I could go about finding it?

On the server side, I open two connections and put them into a tuple so I can cycle through them with a loop:

```
    (self.con1, rec1) = self.s.accept()
    (self.con2, rec2) = self.s.accept()
    self.con = (self.con1, self.con2)
```

Would the following be sufficient code to close these connections?

```
    self.con1.close()
    self.con2.close()
```

Could it be possible that maybe putting the connections into the tuple is creating a new copy of connections that are maybe lingering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's normal. TCP defines a TIME_WAIT state for ports that last for a few minutes (twice the Maximum Segment Lifetime), during which they can't be re-used. It's a data integrity measure. You can overcome it by setting the `SO_REUSEADDR` option before binding the socket.

Comment: `SO_REUSEADDR`/`SO_REUSEPORT` allows you to use a port that is still in `TIME_WAIT`. To avoid `TIME_WAIT` in the first place, you might be able to use `SO_LINGER` to disable lingering when closed, but that does not always work. Another option is to use `shutdown(SD_RECEIVE)` only and not `shutdown(SD_SEND)` or `shutdown(SD_BOTH)`. If you close your end of a connection first AND send a `FIN`, you will go into `TIME_WAIT`.  But you should not avoid `TIME_WAIT` in 99.9999999% of cases, it exists for a reason to protect sessions from corruption.

Comment: @RemyLebeau SO_REUSEPORT is for UDP, indeed for multicast if I remember correctly. Nothing to do with TIME_WAIT. The way to avoid TIME_WAIT is to be the end that receives the first close, which is yet another argument in favour of connection pooling. `shutdown()` doesn't really have much to do with it. I never post about SO_LINGER as I don't believe anybody anywhere should mess with it.

Comment: `SO_REUSEPORT` can be used for TCP as well.  It allows multiple threads/processes to listen on the same port, each one calling `accept()`. A new client can be accepted by any one of them. Useful for pooling and load balancing. As for `TIME_WAIT` you only enter it if you are the first party to send `FIN`. No `FIN` no `TIME_WAIT`. Of course, skipping `FIN` is not nice to the other party.